# Problem in FullSimplify with assumptions:

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

For the vector $\psi  = \{ 0,F1,\alpha ,0,\beta ,0,0,F2\} $, I am trying to simplify ${\left\| \psi  \right\|^2}$ where
$\alpha  = \cos (\theta )$,
$\beta  = \sin \left[ \theta  \right]$,
$F1 = {{\cos \left[ \theta  \right]\nu } \over {{{\left( {1 - {{\rm{e}}^{ - {{2\pi \Omega } \over r}}}} \right)}^{1/2}}}}$, and
$F2 = {{\sin \left[ \theta  \right]\nu {{\rm{e}}^{ - {{\pi \Omega } \over r}}}} \over {{{\left( {1 - {{\rm{e}}^{ - {{2\pi \Omega } \over r}}}} \right)}^{1/2}}}}$, and  all parameters ($\theta, \nu,\Omega,r $) are reals. I used:

```
\[Alpha] = Cos[\[Theta]];
\[Beta] = Sin[\[Theta]];
F1 = (Cos[\[Theta]] \[Nu])/(1 - E^(-((2 \[Pi] \[CapitalOmega])/r)))^(
  1/2);
F2 = ( Sin[\[Theta]] \[Nu] E^(-((\[Pi] \[CapitalOmega])/r)))/(1 - 
    E^(-((2 \[Pi] \[CapitalOmega])/r)))^(1/2);

\[Psi] = {0, F1, \[Alpha], 0, \[Beta], 0, 0, F2};

FullSimplify[
 Norm[\[Psi]]^2, {\[CapitalOmega], \[Nu], r, \[Theta]} \[Element] 
  Reals]
```

But Mathematica still considers $r$ is complex, where the output contains the term ${\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \left[ {{1 \over r}} \right]$.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: What happens if you add `&& Abs[r] > 0` to the assumptions?

Comment: @J.M. yes it works. Thank you.

Comment: In my case (Mma 12.1, Win10) it contains no such term. This can be a consequence of a different definition of r somewhere in your code during the current session. Try to clear r right before the simplification.

Comment: `Simplify[Norm[\[Psi]]^2 // ComplexExpand, {\[CapitalOmega], \[Nu], r, \[Theta]} \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: The simplest solution would be simply `ComplexExpand[Norm[\[Psi]]^2]`